# How do I store the values of an object type in an array and call them (C#)?

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, sorting, for-loop

I've the following class:

```
public class Object
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
    }
```

I create a new array of the object: 
`Object[] Object= new Object[1];`

I assign it a value, Object[0] = new Object() { Name = "T", Price = 32};

But then, when I try to print the values, using foreach like this:

```
foreach(var a in Object) 
Console.WriteLine(a);
```

I get Namespace.Object;

How can I fix this and get the actual values of Name and Price per row and store multiple values of it?

Comment: First off I'd suggest finding a better name than `Object`.  But basically you need to override the `ToString` method.

Answer (score 1):

`Console.WriteLine()` will attempt to convert `a` to a string, in turn calling `a.ToString()`.

You can [override the `ToString()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring#notes-to-inheritors) if needed:

```cs
public class Object
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"[Name: {Name}, Price: {Price}]";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing instance, [override `.ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method) method in `Object` class and while printing convert your object to `string`.

```
//First of all, give meaningful name
public class Product
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int Price { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Price of product {this.Name} is {this.Price}";
    }
}
```

Now just iterate over each product. `Console.WriteLine()` will internally calls `ToString()` which you overridden in `Product` class

```
 //Here Products is array of Product object
 foreach(var product in Products) 
    Console.WriteLine(product);
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine` will internally call `ToString` so you don't have to explicitly call it.

Comment: Ohh, I was not aware of it. Thanks @juharr Everyday is a school day ;)